# GORM tablePerHierarchy false, foreign key

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have in my models:

```
class ContestParticipant{
    static mapping = {
        id generator: "uuid"
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
    String id
    Contest sweepContest
    Client client
    String email
}


class Winner extends ContestParticipant{

...

}
```

my question is, why in the table Winner is not creating a FK to its parent table?!

the same questio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620158/in-grails-setting-tableperhierarchy-false-doesnt-create-a-foreign-key-relations which wasnt answered!

thanks

Comment: im not seeing a relationship from Foo to any other class

Comment: I edited my post, now we have all the objects inside ContestParticipant!!... but the problem here is why the table Winner doenst have FK to  ContestParticipant!?!

Answer (score 1):

In the hibernate documentation it says

> The three subclass tables have primary
>   key associations to the superclass
>   table so the relational model is
>   actually a one-to-one association

in its example of table per subclass.

I think this means that you wont see a foreign key.  You should see the primary key of the ContentParticipant match the primary key of the Winner, for the Winner row in the db.